# How are some Linux device drivers automatically loaded/unloaded?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

With regards to Linux device drivers, my *understanding* (obtained from reading [this excellent DIY article](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux)) is that there are essentially six events/parts of a device driver "lifecycle":

- `Load` - the compiled driver is loaded as a Linux kernel module via `insmod`
- `Open` - the device is opened/readied for usage
- `Read`/`Write` - the device is used
- `Close` - the device is closed/disconnected, currently no longer useable (unless re-opened)
- `Release` - the driver (now a kernel module) is unloaded from the kernel via `rmmod`

Thanks to that article and countless others, I can now write a whole bunch of C code to implement hooks/callbacks for what should happen when the kernel issues `Open`, `Read`, `Write` and `Close` commands. But, it seems that the driver must be loaded/released **manually** by issuing an `insmod` (load) and `rmmod` (release) at the shell.

However, I know this can't be the case because certain devices, like USB, allow you to connect/disconnect them dynamically/on-the-fly, and their respective drivers must be automatically loaded/released on-the-fly as well.

So this stirs up the following question: **How do certain technologies, like USB, automate the execution of `insmod` and `rmmod` (hence the dynamic loading/releasing of USB device drivers)?**

Comment: http://linux-hotplug.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks @MarcB (+1) - can you confirm that [udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) has replaced `hotplug` and that its respective library, `libudev` is what I would need to code against for hotplugging device drivers? Thanks again!

Comment: FYI not every device driver is implemented as a loadable module.  Nor is every loadable module a device driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its based on linux hotplug. The below link may useful for you.

http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-14-sect-7

Answer (score 1):

Hotplug! cf man udev : in /lib or /usr/lib or /etc/udev/udev.d with priorities, you have rules([0-9]*descriptionName.rules) which make matching between device properties from pci and fitting module to load.
Cf

> sudo udevadm monitor --env

to see the messages